# Using max function to group max value by unique ID in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, expression, maximum

I have been using the maximum function to group max value by unique `"id"`;

```
maximum("Ni_ppm_1", group_by:="Hole_id")
```

The function pulls the maximum `"Ni_ppm_1"` value per unique `"Hole-id"`.

Below is a snip of the dataset

[image]

Is it possible to get the function to pull out the `"from"` and `"To"` associated with the maximum Ni value?

The `"From"` / `"To"` is the depth of the sample.

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`maximum()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#maximum) function together with the [`array_agg()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#array-agg) function to achieve this:

```
array_get(
    with_variable('max_ppm',
                  maximum("Ni_ppm_1", group_by:="Hole_id"),
                  array_agg(expression:="Ni_ppm_1"  || '-' || "From" || '-' || "To",
                            group_by:="Hole_id",
                            filter:="Ni_ppm_1"=@max_ppm)
                ),
    0)
```

in the first part the `maximum` will be assigned to the variable `max_ppm` and then the expression `"Ni_ppm_1"  || '-' || "From" || '-' || "To"` will be collected into an array with the same `group_by` and the filter `Ni_ppm_1 = @max_ppm`. The [`array_get()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#array-get) selects the first (and only) entry from the result array.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the `From` value for the maximum "Ni_ppm_1" value per unique "Hole-id" with this expression:

```
attribute (
    get_feature (
        @layer, 
        'Ni_ppm_1',
        maximum(
            "Ni_ppm_1", 
            group_by:="Hole_id"
        )
    ),
    'From'
)
```

Replace `'From'` in the second last line with `'To'` to get the according `To` value. To get all these values (including your max value with the expression you provided) as output, there are different options - please specifiy for which one you'd like to get more information (if so):

1. Concatenate, use pipes `||`  to get a string with these values in the form `[expression1] || [expression2] || [expression3]` - add `', ' ||` after each `||` to separate the values with a comma+space.
2. Create an array of these values.
3. Create a map, thus a list of key:value pairs, comparable to Python dictionaries, see Wikipedia: [Associative array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array)